# create custom editor window kendo js grid

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a grid which i want to be able to open up a kendoWindow on edit instead of the standard popup.

```
         editable: "popup",
            edit: function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                console.log("EDIT");
                $.ajax({
                    url: '@Url.Action("EditProductView", "Product")',
                    type: 'POST',
                    dataType: 'html',
                    cache: false,
                    success: function (data) {
                        console.log(data);
                        $("edit-product-window").kendoWindow({
                            content: data,
                            title: "Product"
                        });
                    },
                    error: function (xhr, error) {
                    },
                });
            },
```

I'm doing it like the above code but when editable is "popup" it gets the html for my custom popup but it also opens up the default popup window. If i change editable to just true it doesn't trigger the edit event. How can i trigger the edit event and also prevent the default edit event from happening?

Answer (score 0):

The reason you can't use the **edit function** even after you add the `e.preventDefault()` is because it's invoked after the popup is created.

> This is the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18915921/how-to-prevent-opening-of-kendo-grid-editor-pop-up-in-javascript)  lead me to this.

To easily prove it you can use a `debugger;` before your `e.preventDefault()`. There you will see that the popup already there before you can do anything about it.

> The **workaround**, here is a [kendo dojo](http://dojo.telerik.com/eLUKi)

But if you really have to do it the workaround i suggested is using the **row template** and bind a **click/doubleclick event** on it.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this
    editable:
{mode:"popup",
   template:"your template"
      }